Are perfboard, stripboard, and matrix board essentially the same thing?
Are the terms perfboard, matrix board and stripboard referring essentially to the same thing since they are often used interchangeably?

Perfboard, matrix board, and stripboard are similar but not identical.
Perfboard is a type of prototyping board with a grid of holes, allowing for the free placement of components and the use of component leads or wires (in the 'old days' between pins) for connections. It has no copper laminate.
Matrix board is similar to perfboard but features a grid of holes arranged in a matrix, with copper pads around the holes. These boards can be single-sided or double-sided with plated-through holes. Connections are also made with component leads or wires.
Stripboard, also known as Veroboard, has parallel copper tracks on one side, with holes for placing components. The copper tracks make the connections and can be cut or linked to create the circuit layout.
All three are types of prototyping boards.
